# Search without first letter mysql

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to search without first letter? I have some query that using soundex I want to search only **ammer** without **H** but seems it is not working to my current query

```
╔════╦══════════════╗
║ id ║ item_name    ║
╠════╬══════════════╣
║  1 ║ Hammer       ║
║  2 ║ Nails        ║
║  3 ║ Woods        ║
╚════╩══════════════╝
```

> 

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE SOUNDEX(item_name) LIKE CONCAT(TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM SOUNDEX('ammer')), '%')
```

> 

```
Expected Result:
    ╔════╦══════════════╗
    ║ id ║ item_name    ║
    ╠════╬══════════════╣
    ║  1 ║ Hammer       ║
    ╚════╩══════════════╝
```

Please help me what query is missing?

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not working"? Please provide more information including:
1- Sample dataset
2- Your desired query output

Comment: @SoheilRahsaz I add some of table, currently its not searchable when you put "ammer" to my query

Answer (score 0):

You can search based on a regular expression

```
SELECT *
FROM product 
WHERE SOUNDEX(item_name) REGEXP '^.ammer'
```

Comment: This is wrong. Take a look at this link to see the output of the `soundex`.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex

Answer (score 0):

Select * from table where item_name like '_ammer%'